# Interpolating data between two known functions matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have two lines `y1 = -a1*x1 + c1` for `theta =30` and `y1 = -a2*x1 + c2` for `theta = 45` 
is it possible to interpolate a equation for `y1` for `theta` between 30 and 45 in matlab ? The lines are almost parallel to each other. Anyone has an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Please describe what your interpolation should match. Should it simply connect both lines with a direct line, should the derivation be equal at 30 and 45? We don't know what data is described, thus cant decide what is best.

Comment: So for `x1` point, you want to interpolate in the `y` direction assuming coordinate [30, -a1*x1 + c1] and [45, -a2*x1 + c2] to find y2 such that [40, y2]?

Comment: This is math rather than programming!

Answer (score 2):

You can interpolate the coeff `a` and `c`:

```
w = (theta - 30) / (45 - 30 ); % w = 0 for theta = 30 and w = 1 for theta = 45
aTheta = a2 * w + a1 * ( 1 - w );
cTheat = c2 * w + c1 * ( 1 - w );
yTheta = -aTheta * x + cTheta * y;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 1:10;
a30 = 1;
a45 = 1.1;
c30 = 0;
c45 = 3;
y30 = -a1*x + c1;
y45 = -a2*x + c2;
```

Now to find `y40` we can just interpolate the curve parameters (i.e. slope (`a`) and offset (`c`))

```
a40 = interp1([30,45], [a30, a45], 40);
c40 = interp1([30,45], [c30, c45], 40);
```

And now our interpolated `y40` is

```
y40 = -a40*x + c40;

plot(x,y30,x,y45,x,y40);
```